# jQuery sort in div - complicated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div called #usersInRoom which is the placeholder for the inner divs.

Currently i have 2 rows /2 entries in the div.

But my question is, how can i via. jQuery update the entries to sort by "exp"?

Now it shows "Stefanie" first with "6" exp. And Bare Kald Mig Jesper with 14 exp. last.

How can i sort it, so it outputs the entries with highest exp first?

```
<div id="usersInRoom">
    <div class="entry in_room" id="userInRoom-2" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:32px">
                        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/c33.33.414.414/s200x200/996882_221295918024677_1913237122_n.jpg" style="height:32px;width:32px">
                    </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle"><strong>Stefanie Pedersen</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" style="vertical-align:middle;color:#999"><span id="exp-2">6</span> exp.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="entry in_room" id="userInRoom-1" style="background-color: rgb(155, 229, 162);">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:32px">
                        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc1/c176.49.608.608/s200x200/429356_10151257167066983_1091687280_n.jpg" style="height:32px;width:32px">
                    </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle"><strong>Bare Kald Mig Jesper</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" style="vertical-align:middle;color:#999"><span id="exp-1">14</span> exp.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing the values from database ,you can sort using sql ORDER BY 'exp' ASC or DESC in the query in backend to populate reults.then you can get sorted results in the first place.
`OR`

if you want to sort it on the client side,then try using jueery data tables .
for example
 https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

Comment: Yes, but i am not. Else i would tell it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with current code using jquery in this way: 
First add a class to the experience span.

```
<span id="exp-2" class="exp">6</span>
```

And then the jquery:

```
arr=$("#usersInRoom").find(".exp");
```

And now to select the parent div:

```
$(arr[i]).parents(".entry_in_room")
```

Sorting could be done by accessing text of the elements.

```
$(arr[i]).text()
```

But Ideally, why do you require such nesting? The data could be easily handled within a Table element. There's no no need of separate tables. And if you use a single table, there are many jquery plugins available for that.

Comment: I'll do in this way, because that is the only way i can do this. I've done this, but how can i "change" the divs in the placeholder? 
var arr=$("#usersInRoom").find(".exp");
$.each(arr, function(e){
    var eq= arr[e];
    numbers.push(eq);
});

Comment: after getting and storing mydivs[i]=$(eq).parents(".entry_in_room"), sort this array and append it to #usersInRoom. Basically when sorting the numbers, sort mydivs also,and then append. Also you are using numbers.push(eq), maybe what you need is number.push($(eq)).text() - to get the value and not the element